# QTP+VM: Why is the Click command not executed when I'm not conncted to the VM via Remote Desktop?

Tags: vmware, scheduling, qtp, siebel

I'm using QTP 10 together with VMWare to test a Siebel Application.
I'm executing the following code to click on a Save button.

```
Browser("Siebel").Dialog("Filedownload").WinButton("Save").Click
```

The code works perfectly fine when I'm connected to the VM via Remote Desktop.

On the other side, when I'm starting the QTP test through the scheduler, without having a Remote Desktop connection, the code above fails without any error message. The WinButton is simply not clicked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add from my experience.

In some companies I worked for I couldn't change screensaver or standby settings due to security policy. A PC was bringing up screensaver during long synchronization periods (like generating really big report), and execution was broken.

To avoid that I created simple "Anti Sleep" function that slightly "moves" mouse every 5 minutes. 
http://automation-beyond.com/2009/08/18/anti-sleep-function/

```
Private Const SleepTime_Max = 300 ‘ 5 minutes
Public Function AntiSleep()
Dim iter
Dim objTimer
Dim objDeviceReplay
Dim intTimeElapsed

 Set objTimer = MercuryTimers(“AntiSleep”)
 intTimeElapsed = CInt(objTimer.ElapsedTime/1000)

 If intTimeElapsed = 0 Then
  MercuryTimers(“AntiSleep”).Start
  Exit Function
 End If

 If intTimeElapsed < SleepTime_Max Then
  Exit Function
 End If

Set objDeviceReplay = CreateObject(“Mercury.DeviceReplay”)

 For iter = 100 To 110
   objDeviceReplay.MouseMove iter,300
 Next

MercuryTimers(“AntiSleep”).Start

Set objDeviceReplay = Nothing

End Function
```

Example of using it in a custom synchronization function:
http://automation-beyond.com/2009/08/20/gui-object-synchronization-custom-function/

Thank you,
Albert Gareev

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but I had to use "objDeviceReplay.MouseClick 100, 200, 0", since a MouseMove only did not keep the VM connection awake.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's absolutely correct, if it's under remote connection you have to click too (If it's on the regular desktop moving only is enough).
I just do not have clicking as a default action in a sync loop because sometimes clicking might trigger something you wouldn't want.
But in an upper level sync loop I have a codepiece periodically clicking on the titlebar of the window which is generating report or doing some other thinking stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

QTP can't interact with a locked desktop, that's why it'll only work for you when logged in interactively either locally or over RDP. It's a well known limitation of QTP, most automation engineers go through this pain at some point. :)

To be more specific, it can't interact with Win32 objects (can't think of a better way of putting it), so it'll interact with basic browser controls on a locked desktop no problem, but browser popups and Windows applications can't be interacted with in those circumstances.

I strongly recommend (if your system policy allows) that you install something like [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com) or another VNC variant to interact with your remote machines. That way you can leave the remote machine's desktop logged on and active at all times. Since it's a VM that shouldn't cause you any major security problems either. Make sure you turn off any screen savers and don't auto-lock the desktop too. QTP should work just fine for you if you do that.